# XML to dropdown list using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This code below works perfectly without this line: ".Insert(0, new SelectListItem(){Text = "", Value="", Selected = false})"...Basically I am trying to add a blank value to the dropdown, the error I get with this line is "Cannot convert from void to SelectListItem." Any ideas on how to add the blank properly?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemPost.txtVal,
    new List<SelectListItem>(
        (from node in
             System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(Model.itemQuestionRowDef.SupportingXML).Descendants("option")
         select new SelectListItem
             {
                 Text = node.Value,
                 Value = node.Attribute("value").Value,
                 Selected = node.Attribute("value").Value == Model.itemPost.txtVal ? true : false
             }
         )
        ).Insert(0, new SelectListItem(){Text = "", Value="", Selected = false}),
    new { @class = "tobeFilled", id = "id_" + Model.counter, Name = "questionLst[" + Model.counter + "]." + "txtVal" })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, `List<T>.Insert()` doesn't return anyhting, so you can't use it in an expression.

Instead, you can call LINQ's `Concat()` method, which returns a new sequence:

```
new[] { new SelectListItem(...) }
.Concat(from node in ...
        select ...
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this new item as the first in the list?

Comment: @RealityDysfunction: That's what my (edited) code does

Comment: All solutions here work, but first one takes the cake. Thanks for the help SLaks.

Answer (score 1):

return type of `Insert` is `void`.It does modify your List.So You need to create and modify your list.then pass it to the function:

```
var list = new List<SelectListItem>(
    (from node in   System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(Model.itemQuestionRowDef.SupportingXML).Descendants("option")
     select new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = node.Value,
             Value = node.Attribute("value").Value,
             Selected = node.Attribute("value").Value == Model.itemPost.txtVal ? true : false
         }));
list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem(){Text = "", Value="", Selected = false});

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.itemPost.txtVal,list,new { @class = "tobeFilled", id = "id_" + Model.counter, Name = "questionLst[" + Model.counter + "]." + "txtVal" });
```